# Making a full-screen sized responsive video div

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a website with a video that shows at the top of the page at full height and full width (not a background – I want to have other divs showing after it). I want it to zoom at the center of the video according to the browser size. I have tried out numerous solutions all over SO and other sites, and I still can't find one that meets my needs.

Everything I found so far was either a non-fullscreen div or a background.

HTML

```
<div class="header-unit">
            <div id="video-container">
                <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
                    <source src="video1.webm" type='video/webm' />
                    <source src="video1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video. Please upgrade your browser!
                </video>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header-unit 
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}

#video-container 
{
    position: absolute;
}

#video-container 
{
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video 
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
}

video.fillWidth
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/511r6gmx/)

How could I do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:** I wanted to resize the video so that the height and width of any browser is filled entirely, enlarging at the center if necessary.

Comment: add code related to your question

Comment: Apply the same thing to your video as you would to the background?

Comment: @Abdulla Sure, though I'm a bit reluctant to add the code because I completely changed it so many times already to no avail

Comment: @Rex adding code will be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this -

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

video.fillWidth
{
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 z-index: -100;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 background-size: cover;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="header-unit">
    <div id="video-container">
        <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.webm" type='video/webm' />
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video. Please upgrade your browser!
        </video>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="wrap">
    <h1>here other tag</h1>    
</div>
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I meant that I wanted to resize the video so that the height and width of any browser was filled entirely, zooming in at the center if necessary.

Comment: I meant to zoom the video so that the height is 100% the browser and the width is at least 100% the browser size.

Answer (score 0):

You tried width:100vw ;height:100vh ?